# Macro to insert line break in excel rows in specific column

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am naïve to macros and I need a macro button to enter line break at the end of every data in the row. I have around 1000 rows of data in specific columns. I need to apply this to selected columns. I am currently using ALT+ENTER, but it is time consuming.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am currently using below code

```
Sub Macro
Dim Stem As Variant
Stem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1").Range("C2")
Range ("K2").Select
Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = Stem & Chr(10) & ""
End Sub
```

Above code copies only C2 data and paste in K2 and apply formula. But I need all data in column C2:C  to be copied and pasted in K2:K.

Thanks

Comment: What code are you currently using, and what doesn't it do correctly?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you have asked it to do - copy C2 to K2. You may need to look up selecting a range, rather than a cell.

Comment: Absolutely, but I don't no how to code that. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that correctly, you want to loop through the copied records in column K and add a line break?
In that case you can use this (this will copy all columns starting from 1) and loop through cells in K starting from 2, you can change that if needed:

```
Sub copyAndNewLine()
'copy column C to K
Columns("C").Copy Destination:=Columns("K")

'loop through all cells in K and add new line
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, "K").Value = Cells(i, "K").Value & vbCrLf
Next i
End Sub
```